# Generalising a problem when two fields $F \ncong K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials, field-theory, rational-numbers

I am trying to generalize a problem that I came across previously.

$\mathbf{ Problem:}$ [Are the fields $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q[\sqrt2]}$ isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3351306/are-the-fields-mathbbq-and-mathbbq-sqrt2-isomorphic)

$\mathbf{Generalisation:}$ Let $F$ and $K$ be two fields of characteristic $0$ and such that $F \subset K$. If there exists a polynomial (of finite degree) $p(x) \in F[x]$ with coefficients from copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $F$ does not contain any root of $p(x)$ but $K$ contains every root of it, then $F\ncong K$.

Proof Attempt:

Any field $F$ with $\mathrm{char \ F=0 }$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$. So, $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $F$ (thereby $K$).

Now, let us assume that despite of the presence of such a polynomial $p(x)$, $F \cong K$. 
Let $p(x)=a_0x^n+a_{1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x+a_n$. We have $p(\beta)=0$, for some $\beta \in K$ but $\beta \notin F$.

Let $\phi: F \mapsto K$ be such an isomorphism. For some $x \in F$,

$\beta=\phi(x) \implies a_r\beta^{n-r}= \phi(a_rx^{n-r})$ $ \ \ \ \ \ ....(*) $ . [This holds due to the fact that any such isomorphism will fix $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $\phi(m)=m$ , $\forall m\in \mathbb{Q}$].

By $(*)$, running $r\in \{1,2,...,n\}$  and adding them gives,

$p(\beta)=0=\phi(p(x)) \implies p(x)=0$. By our assumption, $x \in F$, but $p(x)\neq 0 \ \forall \ x\in F$.  A contradiction.

Is the formulation of the general statement correct? Is my "Proof" correct? Kindly verify.

Comment: Since $\Bbb Q[x] \subseteq F[x] \subseteq K[x]$, then $p(x)$ must have exactly the same number of roots in $F$ as it has in $K$ or the fields can't be isomorphic.  So if $F$ contains no roots of $p(x)$, your conclusion follows if $K$ contains even one root of $p(x)$.

Comment: @RobertShore Now, from that polynomial whose at least one root is missing in $F$, can't we find another polynomial whose all roots are missing in $F$ but $K$ contains all of its roots?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm just pointing out that you are using a stronger assumption than you need to reach your conclusion.  Let $F=\Bbb Q, K= \Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]{3}], p(x)=x^3-3$.

Comment: @RobertShore I agree. Initially I intended to prove the even more general case you mentioned, but then I realized that I am yet to be familiar with the tools required to prove it. Or maybe I am missing something obvious. I will try to prove it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the full strength of this assumption.  All you need is one root in $K$.

Assume $\exists p(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ such that $p(x)$ has at least one root $r \in K$ but $p(x)$ has no roots in $F$.  Then assume $f:F \to K$ is an isomorphism.  Since $f(1)=1$, it follows that $\forall a \in \Bbb Q, f(a)=a,$ so $f(p(x))=p(x)$.  But $p(r)=0 \Rightarrow 0=f^{-1}(0)=f^{-1}(p(r))=p(f^{-1}(r)) \Rightarrow f^{-1}(r)$ is a root of $p$ in $F$, contradicting our hypothesis.

Comment: Won't it be $f(p(x))=p(f(x))$?

Comment: You could use that as an intermediate step, but the point is that $f$ is necessarily the identity on $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Correct if wrong: Since the indeterminate $x$ is from $\mathbb{Q}$, $f(p(x))=p(x)$. Right?

Comment: No, $x$ is an indeterminate.  What's correct is that since the coefficients of $p(x)$ are from $\Bbb Q, \forall x \in F~ f(p(x))=p(f(x)).$

Comment: But in your answer: "Then assume $f:F \to K$ is an isomorphism.  Since $f(1)=1$, it follows that $\forall a \in \Bbb Q, f(a)=a,$ so $\mathbf{f(p(x))=p(x)}$."

Comment: I am not getting why is it. The fixing of $\mathbb{Q}$ is clear to me.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas Write $p(x)=\sum a_n x^n.$  Then because each $a_n \in \Bbb Q, \forall x \in F$ we have $f(p(x))=f(\sum a_n x^n)= \sum f(a_n x^n)= \sum f(a_n)f(x^n)= \sum a_nf(x^n)=p(f(x))$.  That means that $f$ fixes $p$ as a polynomial over an indeterminate $x$, but you can also see directly that roots of $p$ in $F$ must be in $1-1$ correspondence with roots of $p$ in $K$.

Comment: This is clear. But in your answer you have yourself written that $f(p(x))=p(x)$. Look again.

Comment: Viewing $x$ as an indeterminate, what I wrote is correct, because an isomorphism on an abstract polynomial acts only on the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: It is essentially the same, then (notational standpoint)?

Comment: I think that's right.  I edited my comment above to expand on the reasoning, which I hope clears things up a bit.

Comment: I have myself used almost the exact same argument to arrive at $\phi(p(x))=p(\phi(x))$ in my question. The only unclear part was the notation in your answer. Everything else is very neat.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good. You could also just take a nonlinear irreducible factor of $p(X), p'(X)$ that $\beta$ is a root of that so $K$ is a nontrivial field extension of $F.$ Any we know from linear algebra or what not that an isomorphism can't exist.